# I can't upload images to server with ckeditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I installed `ckeditor` with `cfinder` on my PHP website and image-upload works properly; the images show on `ckeditor` content but **images aren't sent to my folders on host**.

What should I do for this problem?

In html form:

```
<textarea name="edit" id="edit" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>

<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'edit',
{
filebrowserImageUploadUrl:'../ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php? 
   command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
});
</script>
```

In ckfinder/config.php:

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
'name'         => 'default',
'adapter'      => 'local',
'baseUrl'      => '/userfiles/',
//  'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder 
user files directory.
'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
'chmodFolders' => 0755,
'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);
```

Comment: check file permissions, double-check file paths, do some debugging and get some information about errors/unexpected behaviour. You provided so little detail that we can't give you much more than generic suggestions

Comment: reopen this question

Comment: it's still not enough info. I asked for a lot more than just code. "do not send" is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: what data should i add ?

Comment: All the things I mentioned in my first comment. e.g. details of the _actual_ file permissions set on the relevant folders/files (not just config code), evidence that you've double-checked the upload path(s) you've configured is correct, and details of any errors/warnings/other output generated by PHP when uploading the files. If you haven't configured PHP to log exceptions and warnings, please do that first (you can easily google how to do it) before re-testing.